# Test SMS messaging using Phonegap app on iPhone without owning an iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, sms

Is there an option to test a phonegap app on an iPhone device for SMS messaging without actually owning an iPhone device (e.g. emulator, online service..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SMS needs a simcard with work. The simulator is not acceptable alternative for a device.
Before releasing any app you should have tested it on a real device.

Also be aware that you can only send a SMS with the official iOS SDK and you should can wether the device is capable of sending SMS messages.